# Is there an iPad app like Snagit for marking up screenshots or pictures with arrows, callouts, dropshadows, torn edges, etc.?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications, screen-capture

I LOVE [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html).

I know that captures can only be done in iOS with the built in Home-Power screenshot function.

But I'm looking for an app that will allow me to edit those shots and add arrows, shadows, edges, callouts, blur, freehand circles, etc.

Is there something that does this well, with a *focus on annotation*?  (So I get that I can do this in Keynote an other apps, but since they're not made for it, it's painful, they can't export the picture back to the photo roll, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are looking mainly for annotation then [Skitch](http://www.evernote.com/skitch/) could be worth a look.
It lacks the more fancy features you asked for (torn edges, blur, etc.) but for basic annotation (arrows, text, freehand) it is quite good.
Although it was acquired by Evernote it is possible to save the annotated image back to the camera roll.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a combination of Pages, PS Express and Strip Design.  They each have unique features.  It would be nice to have an all in one app that did it all.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Grafik Note](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap.-mark-up.-send./id490505997?mt=8), this is designed for iPad

[image]

- Import photo from gallery or by camera
- Drawing line, segment with/without arrow.
- Drawing free curve with/without arrow.
- Drawing outlined/filled rectangle, oval, round rectangle.
- Highlight color.
- Free text.
- Drawing speech bubble with rectangle/oval/ round rect
- Enable to change outline and fill color, editable dash style, enable to change line width
- Enable styling text color, font, size and alignment.
- File manager which supports create folder/rename/copy/paste/move.
- Sharing your annotation photo with the world via email, Facebook, Twitter ...